# Why can't I connect to localhost server from localhost client (cors error)?

Tags: express, socket.io, cors, localhost, localserver

I have a local (Angular) client running on port 4200 (http://localhost:4200) and a local (express) server on port 5000 (http://localhost:5000). Whenever I try to connect to my server, I get this message.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NU7H' from origin 
'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here is the code to start my local server

```
@injectable()
export default class App {
  app: express.Application;

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.config();
    this.bindRoutes();
  }

  // Middlewares config
  private config(): void {
    this.app.use(cors());
    this.app.use(express.json());
    this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  }

  bindRoutes(): void {
    this.app.use('/', router);
  }
}
```

Here is the code where I set up my socket

```
private _ioServer: SocketIO.Server;

initSocket(server: http.Server) {
    this._ioServer = new SocketIO.Server(server);

    this.connectChat(); // Chat namespace
    this.connectStream(); // Game board streaming namespace
}
```

I tried with Postman, everything is working.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any malicious site can take advantage of your cookies stored in the system called [Cross-site request forgery](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf)

Any browser tries to prevent you from these attacks so they disable CORS.

**Shorthand Fix [Not recommended] :** There are many plugins out there you can use for your local testing that disables these checks on browser.

**Proper Fix:** Use an Express middleware to apply `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in your header when response is returned back from the server.

Gist is that when browser sends the request to your server it will append `Origin: http://localhost:3000` to the headers. Reacting to this request from browser, server should return a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to specify which origins can access the server's resources.

You can be strict here to return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200` or open your gates by sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Here is the quick code to have an express middleware:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

app.get('/jokes/random', (req, res) => {
  request(
    { url: 'https://joke-api-strict-cors.appspot.com/jokes/random' },
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: err.message });
      }

      res.json(JSON.parse(body));
    }
  )
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on ${PORT}`));
```

**Source:** https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9

P.S, [this](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9) is a very good read for your understanding of CORS.

Answer (score 0):

In the index.js file of your middleware add:
`app.use(cors())`